# Aplicar una clase a un input si tiene texto dentro

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Tengo un formulario, en el cual los input text tienen unas clases para que el placeholder una vez se tiene seleccionado el input text pase a ser un label, el problema es que una vez deja de estar seleccionado este pasa de nuevo a su lugar, sin importar si tiene texto dentro lo cual queda muy mal.
Eso se hace con la clase "nk-toggled" que se aplica cuando está seleccionado el input text, en teoría está en el código pero no sé porque no funciona.

Así se ve normal
[image: Así se ve normal]

Así cuando tiene el focus
[image: Así cuando tiene el focus]

Así cuando pierde el focus y sigue con texto adentro
[image: Así cuando pierde el focus y sigue con texto adentro]

El código javascript para eso es el siguiente:

```js
$(".nk-int-st")[0] && ($("body").on("focus", ".nk-int-st .form-control", function() {
  $(this).closest(".nk-int-st").addClass("nk-toggled")
}), $("body").on("blur", ".form-control", function() {
  var p = $(this).closest(".form-group, .input-group"),
    i = p.find(".form-control").val();
  p.hasClass("fg-float") ? 0 == i.length && $(this).closest(".nk-int-st").removeClass("nk-toggled") : $(this).closest(".nk-int-st").removeClass("nk-toggled")
})), $(".fg-float")[0] && $(".fg-float .form-control").each(function() {
  var i = $(this).val();
  0 == !i.length && $(this).closest(".nk-int-st").addClass("nk-toggled")
});
```

Comment: Para poder encontrar el fallo haría falta un [Ejemplo mínimo verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), Mas allá del código JS, no tenemos el código del DOM en esos momentos. A simple vista parece que el problema está en el `IF` de una linea, ¿`p` tiene la clase `fg-float` cuando se ejecuta el evento?

Comment: @Parra pues [aquí hay una demo](https://colorlib.com/polygon/notika/form-elements.html) de su autor.

Comment: @Ragnaval agrega todas las partes relvantes a tu pregunta, las ligas pueden caducar, y tu ejemplo puede tener errores tipográficos que no podríamos reproducir a partir de código de una pagina que pudo haber cambiado el día de ayer. Ademas el sitio te provee de snippets que es una forma de tener código ejecutable en la misma pregunta, cosa que ayuda con la despuración y eliminación de errores comunes, además de que permite ver el mensaje de error exacto si es que lo hay.

Comment: Adicionalmente te recomiendo probar con el selector `input:placeholder-shown`

Answer (score 1):

se podría obtener el valor de ese `input` y validar si tiene o no algún texto para aplicarle la clase que dices que activa el `label` (`nk-toggled`), es decir:

```
<input type="text" class="js-dni">

$(document).ready(function(){
  let inputElement = $('.js-dni');

  if (inputElement.val() === '')
    inputElement.addClass('nk-toggled');  
  else
    inputElement.removeClass('nk-toggled');
});
```